# TFS: How to Automatically create sub tasks for story

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am new to TFS. If I have a story in TFS, how to generate the sub tasks(such as Test, Code, Code Review etc) under the story automatically when the status of the story changes from New to Committed. Can we use any queries to do it or to create such template?

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism, your best options are:

- create your own tool to create the Story **and** the Tasks using C#, Powershell or another .Net-based language
- write a Server Plugin, triggered by the state change event that creates the children
- use an existing Plugin, like our [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/) or Richard's [VSTS Service Hooks DSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-ServiceHooks-DSL)

Probably the latter option is the simplest and easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Those activities are better expressed as backlog columns as opposed to tasks.